# Why the HtmlEncode doesn't encode this char?

Tags: c#, html, encoding, html-entities

This is the code :

```
Response.Write("asd1 X : " + HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("×"));
Response.Write("asd2 X : " + HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("✖"));
```

The fist one is :

```
asd1 X : &#215; // OK, ENCODED AS HTML ENTITIES
```

the second no, just ✖ :

```
asd2 X : ✖
```

which kind of char is that? Also, if I try [here](http://htmlentities.net/) the result is :

```
asd1 X : &times;
asd2 X : &amp;#10006;
```

What?? Why this differences?

Comment: Is the character UTF-8, or Windows 1251?

Comment: Uhm...but entities could be universal, no matter about the charset, am I wrong?

Comment: Looks like Unicode character [2716](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2716/index.htm)

Comment: The OUTPUT could be universal, but how does the function know whether the input is UTF-8 or Win-1251?

Comment: That's a right question. In fact : how can I know it? I copied/pasted from a website...I think it will also copy the charset...uhm...

Comment: @markzzz, entities are universal, but not all utilities handles all range of entities. Appearly `HttpUtility` doesn't. But if you try `Microsoft.Security.Application.AntiXss.HtmlEncode`, you'll get the wanted result. And here's a SO talks about the two. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608854/what-is-the-difference-between-antixss-htmlencode-and-httputility-htmlencode

Comment: Why do you need it to be encoded as a numeric entity reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best guest is that not all strings has a entity representation. The [Heavy multiplication X](http://www.danshort.com/HTMLentities/index.php?w=dingb) is just one of the many that don't.

To elaborate Oded's link, `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode` only encodes characters in [ISO 8859-1 (Latin-1)](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html#iso-88591). Since the Heavy Multiplication X is out of this range, the function doesn't handle it.

If you try `Microsoft.Security.Application.AntiXss.HtmlEncode("✖");`, you'll get the HTML entity in `&#10006;`.

Answer (score 7):

In the MSDN page for [`HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73z22y6h.aspx), you will find this comment:

> It encodes all character codes from decimal 160 to 255 (both inclusive) to their numerical entity (e.g. `&#160;`)

`&times;` (`×`) is the same as `&#xD7;` / `&#215;` on my computer, so will get encoded, but since `✖` is `&#x2716;` / `&#10006;`, it will not be.

You can use [the overload of `HtmlEncode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ew0dw8s.aspx) that takes a `TextWriter` based on the wanted Encoding.

Comment: Using the overloaded method doesn't produce a HTML entity. It just outputs the big X. using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(@"c:\temp\test.txt")){HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("✖", tw);}

Comment: @RayCheng - Why are you expecting a numeric entity reference? Why do you need it?

Comment: I think the OP's intend is trying to get the HTML entity. But with `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode`, it's not possible for that particular character because of the limitation. So the overloaded method still does not provide the wanted result.

Comment: @RayCheng - I wouldn't expect it to either.