# Method to use for output filtering in razor asp.net

Tags: asp.net, razor

What method should i use for output filtering in c# asp.net razor

```
AntiXss.HtmlEncode
```

or

```
HttpUtility.HtmlEncode
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can choose the answer yourself:

- [What is the difference between AntiXss.HtmlEncode and
  HttpUtility.HtmlEncode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608854/what-is-the-difference-between-antixss-htmlencode-and-httputility-htmlencode)

  OR
- [Differences Between AntiXss.HtmlEncode and HttpUtility.HtmlEncode
  Methods](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/securitytools/archive/2009/07/09/differences-between-antixss-htmlencode-and-httputility-htmlencode-methods.aspx)