# How to avoid xss on asp:literal control?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
  string myContent="Hello"
  System.Web.UI.Webcontrols.Literal literal1=new System.Web.UI.Webcontrols.Literal();
  literal1.Text="<b>" + myContent + "</b><table><tr><td>HI</td></tr></table>" ;
```

But here I am in a situation where I must perform encoding on literal control text value **(The reason is to prevent the literal control from XSS attack.)**. I am using asp.net c#.

So what I did is,

```
literal1.Text= AntiXssEncoder.HtmlEconde("<b>" + myContent + "</b><table><tr><td>HI</td></tr></table>");
```

So the output would be,

```
<b>Hello</b><table><tr><td>HI</td></tr></table>
```

I don't want the above output(plain text of my markupt) when I do encoding. I want it to render as 
**Hello**
**"HI-> should have been printed inside a html tag "**

Also I know that the result of the literal control will be just a plain text If I do encoding on the literal control. I want to encode the literal control plus I don't want my literal control's text to render as a plain text. any help would be appreciable.

Comment: What is the `Type` of `literal1`?

Comment: Can you give us a complete example? What is the actual problem you are facing?

Comment: Please update your example with the actual problem and with expected output and what is the "wrong" output you are getting now?

Comment: This question's definition has shifted twice. Please close this question and raise a new one called 'how to avoid xss using asp literal'.

Comment: @Davesoft That is true, there was nothing in the original question about xss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to your initial question: To prevent XSS insert the text into a `Label` and add that to a `HtmlGenericControl` of type "b" to sourround it with a bold-tag like this:

```
HtmlGenericControl bold = new HtmlGenericControl("b");
Label myContent = new Label();
myContent.Text = "Hello and some special characters <>";
bold.Controls.add(myContent);
```

The `Label`-Control will encode every special character inside, which should prevent any XSS attack.

For the new table-part of your question: I suggest not to construct your whole DOM inside of a `Literal`. That is pretty bad style and should only be used, if there's no other way. Use the available classes (i.e. `Table`) in the API of ASP.NET instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do:

```
literal1.Text= "<b>" + HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(myContent) + "</b>";
```

Or better yet, use label-control add css-class to it with font-weight: bold;

Comment: Thanks. I already tried what you did. but still the code is vulnerable to XSS attack. Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: You should use HttpUtility.HtmlEncode for the input to sanitize it.

Comment: I have been advised not to use HttpUtility to  prevent XSS attacks. Can you advise

Comment: Well read yourself https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608854/what-is-the-difference-between-antixss-htmlencode-and-httputility-htmlencode it might be better to use AntiXssEncoder in some scenarios

Comment: opened a new Question "to avoid xss using asp literal"